# Fit multiple divs to it's parent DIV height

Tags: html, css

This is my div structure. `#myMenu` height is dynamic, I want to make all DIVs fit inside `myMenu`'s height. How do I do that?

I tried wrapping all divs which are inside `myMenu` inside of an another div but I couldn't achieve what I want.

```
#myMenu{
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 600px; /*this value is dynamic*/
}
.gents{
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: url(logo1.png);
}
.col{
    width: 200px;
}

<div id="myMenu">
   <div class="col">
       <div class="gents"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <div class="gents"></div>
   </div>
   <div class="col">
       <div class="gents"></div>
   </div>
   <div id="other">                
   </div>
</div>
```

**EDIT:**

Expected output (all divs fit inside #myMenu):

[image]

Comment: Currently looking like:  http://jsfiddle.net/u108h68x/ what is your expected output?

Comment: if you are trying to add the culmns next to each others you should use float??

Comment: @Beki You need something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/u108h68x/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's and easy apply following CSS will give you your expected output:

```
#myMenu{
    background-color: #f00;
    height: 600px; /*this value is dynamic*/
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
.gents{
    width:100%;
    padding-bottom:100%;
    background-size:cover;
    background-image: url(logo1.png);
}
.col{
    width: 200px;
    border:1px solid yellow;
}

.col20{
    height:20%;
}
.col40{
    height:40%;
}
```

Check: [Fiddle Link Here.](http://jsfiddle.net/u108h68x/1/)